# Spyder launching

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Hi I'm new to Anaconda and Spyder and I'm having some problems when running spyder. 
Firstly, when I write "spyder" in Terminal, while it starts it gives me this code:

```
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
js: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///*****/*******/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/help/static/css/default.css
```

I've found that if write "export EVENT_NOKQUEUE=1" before running spyder, all the "[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0" messages disappear, but I have to write it every time I want to run spyder. I haven't found any solution to the "js: Not allowed to load local resource" problem.

Moreover, when I open spyder the console shows the following message:

> An error ocurred while starting the kernel
>   Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the ipykernel and cloudpickle modules installed on it. Without these modules is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
>
> You can install them by running in a system terminal:
>
> pip install ipykernel cloudpickle
>
> or
>
> conda install ipykernel cloudpickle

I've installed ipykernel and cloudpickle but it doesn't work and continues showing the message.

What should I do? Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: do you have more than one installation of python. i.e. both base python, and conda?

Comment: This looks very broken, how did you go about installing Anaconda? Also, what OS? Did you set Anaconda as the default system python?

Comment: 1. Appart from anaconda I have Pycharm, Visual Studio code and Sublime text

Comment: 2. I have macOs High Sierra version 10.13.1

Comment: 3. When I started spyder for the first time the system showed a notification saying that spyder wanted to access the computer files, the network or something like that. There were two options Deny or Allow and I clicked Deny. Can it be because of that?